# Group of order $n=pq$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

Let $G$ be a group of order $n=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers and let $x$ $\in$ $G$. My question is how hard is to compute $x^{-1}$ in $G$ ?

Comment: Assuming you can compute powers easily, it is also easy (as it will be one of $x^{p-1}$, $x^{q-1}$ or $x^{pq-1}$).

Comment: Define *hard*...

Comment: @Tobias Kildetof could you tell me why $x^{-1}$ is one of that values ?

Comment: That follows directly from Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @lhf well in prime order group $x^{-1}$ = $x^{p-2}$, so $O(log_2p)$ computations by fast exponentiation, so let say this is easy. In composite order, it`s harder than that ?

Comment: It seem that you are confusing a group of order $pq$ with the group of units modulo $pq$. These are very different things.

Comment: Oups, Thanks @TobiasKildetoft , my bad :D